# create a shortcut that links to my computer

Tags: shortcut

I want to know if I can keep a document on my drive in my folder on my computer but have a sort of shortcut or link on SharePoint that updates whenever I update the document on my computer or goes to my folder to open the document outside of the SharePoint Sites syncing function.

Comment: You can create a link, but why would you?  What is the reason for keeping it on your local machine and not in SharePoint?  You can map a document library to your machine so you can access the file like a network share.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SharePoint you are using?.

If you are using SharePoint 2013, then you can make use of "**SkyDrive Pro**" to attain your requirement.

SkyDrive Pro  --> gives you a place to store and share your business-related files and lets you synchronize your files to a local computer.